# Is it possible to dynamically set the label of a selected option as the label for a repeater field?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

Elementor has the repeater field type, `\Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER`. The documentation (https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-controls/repeater-control/) says that the label for the field can be defined in the `title_field` parameter:

```
'title_field' => '{{{ list_title }}}'
```

This is fine, if the field is a regular text field. But whenever the field type is something selectable, such as `\Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT`, the `{{{ field_name }}}` thing (whatever that is called) utilizes the value of the selected option. That is of course logical, but not practical, because the option value is usually something that is usable in a programming context and not very pleasant for a human to read.

Is there a way to use the label instead? By label, in case of a select element, I mean the inner text of the selected `option` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most sophisticated solution, but it works. It is possible to manipulate key by adding javascript code between `<#` and `#>` brackets.

```
// Define the labels
$labels = [
    'foo' => __('Foo'),
    'bar' => __('Bar'),
];
    
// Convert to JSON
$labels_json = json_encode($labels);

// $this refers to the widget object; context here is the _register_controls() method
$this->add_control('meta_keys', [
    'label' => __('Meta keys'),
    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
    'title_field' => "<# "
        . "let labels = $labels_json; " // Now the labels are available to the javascript
        . "let label = labels[key]; "
        . "#>"
        . "{{{ label }}}",
    'fields' => [
        [
            'name' => 'key',
            'label' => __('Meta key'),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
            'options' => $labels,
            'placeholder' => __('Meta key'),
            'default' => __('Meta key'),
        ]
    ],
]);
```